# Tableau Volume calculation based on Start Date and End Date

Tags: tableau-api, volume, calculated-field

Using Tableau, I need to create a visualisation that shows me the total volume of started and ended work items per day.

Typical sql data consists of columns for each:

Reference (Unique Work Item Reference)
Start Date (Date Work Item Started)
End Date (Date Work Item Finished)

For example, if on the 6th of April 2018, 55 work items were started and 5 items were finished. Each represented date should show in its own line over time.

The issue I'm getting at the moment, when I have start date as a continuous column, it calculates the number of work items started for the end date and not the number of items finished for the end date.

Any help guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[Tableau Public Link](https://public.tableau.com/views/VolumeExample/VolumeDashboard?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&publish=yes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple problem if you correct the shape of your data. You can achieve this by using the pivot functionality in Tableau or Custom SQL(If your data source does not support pivot).

1. Pivot the date columns

[image]
 2. Rename the pivoted fields

[image]

3. Now build the view as below.(null values are due to tasks that are not yet closed, you can just filter it out)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the data is of this form [Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBYku.png)
With this format, you could achieve something like this [Gantt Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTIkM.png)
If you notice, I have created a calculated field called "Duration" which is in size shelf.
the calculated field reads

```
If [Status]="Finished" then
[End Date]-[Start Date] ELSE
TODAY()-[Start Date]
end
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if this is not clear enough

Comment: Thanks Manoraj, except the status column the data in your image is structured the same. However I want to make the calculation on the number of times the start date occurs and the number of times the end date occurs. Based on your image the results would show:

start date for 28/7/2018 = 12
end date for 29/7/2018 = 1 
end date for 30/07/2018 = 2
end date for 31/07/2018 = 2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Even if the Status column is not there in the data source, it can be added using the following code

```
if ISNULL([End Date]) then 
"WIP" else "Finished" end
```

Also, is this how you want to see the information?
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo6ZD.png)

Comment: I dont think I need a status column as I can do the calculation on the fly, it might be more helpful if i share the example I've just uploaded. I will update the main article with the link

Answer (score 0):

Could you please have a look at it and let me know your thoughts?

https://us-east-1.online.tableau.com/t/tableaumanoraj/views/VolumeExample/Dashboard1?iframeSizedToWindow=true&:embed=y&:showAppBanner=false&:display_count=no&:showVizHome=no

Comment: Thank you, but I try to log in and it says my user account is not active, is this a public dashboard?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Jaime!
Please try the below link
https://public.tableau.com/views/VolumeExample_0/Dashboard1?:embed=y&:display_count=yes&publish=yes

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Manoraj, but I think we're missing some key information. The Start Date relates to when a work item was started and the End Date relates to when the work item was completed. I need to show, on the same graph, how many items were started for each date and for that same date how many items had ended. So essentially its a count of the start date and end date for each date.